# Failed to change azure account password from MS Graph Explorer

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, azure-authentication

I am trying to change my password of Azure account from Microsoft Graph Explorer by using this query:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/changePassword
{
"currentPassword": "XXX",
"newPassword": "XXX"
}
```

I got the below **error** while executing that query:

> { "error": { "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied", "message": "Access
> to change password operation is denied.", "innerError": { "date":
> "2022-07-10T05:59:39", "request-id":
> "1ecc339e-62f4-4703-9e92-181f894b9790", "client-request-id":
> "b353d155-13c2-0809-4d83-efb8ae999742" } }

Do I need permission to change my own password? What's the resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/changePassword
Body
{
"currentPassword": "XXXX",
"newPassword": "XXXX"
}
```

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/voSltoc.png)]

Please note that, you need **`Directory.AccessAsUser.All`** permission consented like below:

[image]

***After consenting, I am able to change my password successfully like below:***

[image]

**Reference:**

[user: changePassword - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-changepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)